# how to block access to all ports except certain ones in Windows? Settings locked down by admins

Tags: windows-8.1, security, firewall, ports, whitelist

I want to block all ports on my computer except ones used by applications that I use, blacklisting anything else. Firewall settings are locked down and I need access to a portable application. Minimal to no software changes, no installer.

Please advise me as to whether or not something like this can be done.

running Windows 8.1 and basically all settings are locked via policy.

Comment: We cannot help you bypass domain configured settings for moral reasons, this is outside of the scope of Superuser, and in most cases there are no workarounds anyways.

Comment: Ask your systems administrators how you'd do this in the environment you're in which they maintain and administer to start. It's hard telling what you're trying to accomplish here too based on your wording. Are you trying to download a portable app that's restricted by your Internet access or are you trying to lock down your machine to only allow certain ports only and block everything else?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Stopping yourself from slacking off?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a legitimate need, ask your administrator(s). Otherwise, you cannot do this without admin access or using tools that probably would lead to your termination.